# Windows Forms applications work in Visual Studio 2012, but the compiled .exe files do not

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I've been working on a small desktop app that runs perfectly under Visual Studio, but when I run the .exe file, it gets stuck in infinite loading. I think this may be a problem with my environment:

- The process it creates cannot be terminated via task manager.
- Attempting to attach debugger to the process causes VS to hang.
- Created blank WinForms application - same issue.
- Tried adding logs to a text file, does not seem to reach any of the code.
- Was using local database file initially, but removed later and I haven't specified any other data connections (possible cause?).

Comment: Like I said, trying with a completely new WinForms application had the same issue.

Comment: Please don't abbreviate visual studio year names. With the exception of 2010/10.0, the version numbers don't line up with the years. VS 2012 is version 11.0, VS 2013 is version 12.0, and VS 2015 is version 14.0 (skipping 13 presumably for superstitious reasons)